# How to debug this code of wherefore art thou?

Tags: javascript

**This is the algorithm challenge**:

> Make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching property and value pairs (second argument). Each property and value pair of the source object has to be present in the object from the collection if it is to be included in the returned array.

I've written this, but it is getting errors in some cases. What is wrong in this code?

```
function whatIsInAName(collection,source) {
   var ks = Object.keys(source);
   var vals = [];
   var arr = [];
   var counter = ks.length;

   for(var k in source) {
      vals.push(source[k]);
   }

    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
           if(collection[i].hasOwnProperty(ks[j]) && collection[i][ks[j]] === vals[j]) {
               arr.push(collection[i]);
           }
         }
      }

  return arr;

}
```

**Function calls & Return values**

**(1) Call:**

```
whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" })
```

**(1) Return: (correct)**

```
[{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }]
```

**(2) Call:**

```
whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2 }], { "a": 1 });
```

**(2) Return: (correct)**

```
[{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2 }]
```

**(3) Call:**

```
whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 });
```

**(3) Return: (incorrect)**

```
[{"a":1,"b":2}, {"a":1,"b":2}, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }]
```

**(4) Call:**

```
whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "c": 2 });
```

**(4) Return: (incorrect)**

```
[{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }]
```

Comment: What errors do you get and in what cases do you get them?

Comment: Please take your comment and edit your question to include (and clearly explain) to include that data. Right now, that comment does not clarify your issue.

Comment: whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" })

**Answer:** [{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }] (correct)

whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2 }], { "a": 1 });

**Answer:** [{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2 }] (correct)

whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 })

**Answer:** [{"a":1,"b":2}, {"a":1,"b":2}, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }] (incorrect)
@ScottMarcus

Comment: Again, don't add this information to the **comments**. **EDIT** your original question and include this information along with an explanation. Even now, this comment does not clearly explain the "errors" you are getting and the "cases" that you are getting them in.

Answer (score 0):

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, object) {
    var passValue = Object.keys(object).length;
    var counter = 0;
    var correctObjects = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        var currentObject = collection[i];
        counter = 0

        for (var key in currentObject) {
            var currentValue = currentObject[key];
            if (object[key] === currentValue) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter === passValue) {
            correctObjects.push(currentObject);
        }
    }

    return correctObjects;
}
```

Iterating over the array first, and then checking for each and every value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't break out of the inner `for` loop when you found an element that matched. This leads to if any element in collection that matched multiple times in source will be added to result array duplicately.
 You can fix it by add `break;`

```
arr.push(collection[i]);
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
          const argKeys = Object.keys(source);

            return collection.filter(function(obj) {
              return argKeys.every(function(key) {
                return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
              });
            });
         }
```

Comment: Your reply is appreciated but just posting a snippet of code is not necessarily the best way to go about it? Please elaborate somewhat on what your code does and how it solves the problem of the OP? As that will really help other users in future as well.